# strange IP requests on intranet from ASP sites

Tags: iis, networking, ip, intranet

So I've got a dev IIS server running on the intranet with a fixed IP. I've got a few applications setup in IIS.

I get the strangest behavior: If I load a page with IP address or server name & port, it writes the correct response (as seen in my debugging proxy) but hangs with a white page for a long time while chrome says "waiting for" and it's an incorrect IP address unrelated to the server or application. It does this for several different apps, and each one does the same thing but with random IPs. It waits to connect to wrong local intranet IP. I pinged one, and it's not even an assigned IP on the network.

I can repeat this on a machine without a debugging proxy, and none of the incorrect IPs show up anywhere in the projects.

If I deploy the same apps to an external facing server with proper domains/DNS they work fine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, and is for asking questions related to programming. Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity. Your question belongs on **Server Fault**, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MitchWheat I am a professional salaried programmer of 10 years, haha. We have no support IT staff. I got stuck with this stuff. Think I want to be doing IT? I voted that it belongs on the other stack--which i did not know existed because i'm too busy working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sounds like the DNS entry for your server is not correct. You need to fix the DNS entry to the correct IP by either:

- Setting the correct IP in the hosts file
- Adjusting the DNS record in your DNS server/router
- Contacting network staff

It's definitely possible that your organization has set a "catchall" address for any that goes to their domain but is not specifically defined with a DNS record.

Also, this question is off topic for Stack Overflow and likely belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: haha, we don't have network staff.